# (un)Happy Space User Error when installing RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, railsapps

So I'm completely new to Ruby and Rails and everything to go with it.  I'm working through the [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) book and am stuck at installing RVM.  I'm following the instructions from the article [Install Ruby on Rails on Mac OS X Mavericks](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html).

I get an error message in Terminal after typing in: `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Here's the error message:

```
It looks you are one of the happy *space* users(in home dir name),
RVM is not yet fully ready for it, use this trick to fix it:

    sudo mkdir -p /ChrisTurley.rvm
    sudo chown -R "ChrisTurley:" /ChrisTurley.rvm
    echo "export rvm_path=/ChrisTurley.rvm" >> "/Users/ChrisTurley 1/.rvmrc"

and start installing again.
```

I'm assuming I'm supposed to type in all that "sudo mkdir" stuff into terminal, which I did.  I try reinstalling with `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` and I get the same error message.

Any ideas on what I should do next?

Thanks.

Comment: You could create a new user account on your computer (without a space in the name). I don't know why the fix offered by RVM doesn't work for you. You could ask for help from the RVM maintainers.

Comment: I ended up changing the user account folder name to remove the space and I was able to install RVM no problem.  

Just in case anyone else needs it, here's the Apple help article I found to walk through the process of changing a user account name:  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1428

Comment: Thanks for bringing this issue to my attention. I've updated the article 
[Install Ruby on Rails on Mac OS X Mavericks](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) to include the info you found.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces and change habit of entering spaces when you are dealing with Rails. Change your admin name (user name) remove space.